# Oracle - returning aggregate sum as well as pivoted aggregate sums?

Tags: oracle11g, pivot

I want to return a result set in the following format:

```
YEARMONTH Total ModelA ModelB ModelC
200101    0     0      0      0
200102    10    5      5      0
200103    8     2      2      4
```

where the total is the sum of the hours for all model types grouped by yearmonth, and the individual model columns are the sum of hours per model type grouped by yearmonth. I can get the correct results using the following query with nested selects:

```
select distinct yearmonth,
    sum(a.hours) as Total,
    (select sum(b.hours) from model_hours b
        where model = 'ModelA' and a.yearmonth = b.yearmonth) as ModelA,
    (select sum(b.hours) from model_hours b
        where model = 'ModelB' and a.yearmonth = b.yearmonth) as ModelB,
    (select sum(b.hours) from model_hours b
        where model = 'ModelC' and a.yearmonth = b.yearmonth) as ModelC
from model_hours a
group by yearmonth
order by yearmonth
```

I was curious to try using the pivot function in Oracle 11 to achieve the same results, and am able to get all the results EXCEPT the total hours using the following query:

```
select * from (
    select yearmonth, hours, model
    from model_hours a
)
pivot
( 
    sum(hours)
    for model in ('ModelA', 'ModelB', 'ModelC')
)
order by yearmonth
```

which returns this result:

```
YEARMONTH  ModelA ModelB ModelC
200101     0      0      0
200102     5      5      0
200103     2      2      4
```

I have not been able to figure out how to also get the sum of the hours for all models, grouped by yearmonth, into this resultset. Is it possible? And if so, would it be likely to be more efficient than the nested selects? This particular table has some 200K rows right now.

Answer (score 4):

From forums.oracle.com, there are several similar ways to do it... the most straightforward syntax seems to be:

```
select yearmonth,ModelA + ModelB + ModelC Total,ModelA,ModelB,ModelC from (
    select yearmonth, hours, model
    from model_hours a
)
pivot
( 
    sum(hours)
    for model in ('ModelA' as ModelA, 'ModelB' as ModelB, 'ModelC' as ModelC)
)
order by yearmonth
```

As an aside, the pivoted queries are approximately 100 times faster than the original query with scalar sub-queries!